# How to Resize WEBM Videos

Tags: firefox, video, webm

I find that a lot of the webm videos (or gifv) on imgur and the like are too small to see (yes, my eyesight is horrible).  These types of videos allow for viewing in full screen, but since the source is tiny, blowing them up full screen (especially on a large monitor) results in a lot of pixelating.  I looked for a plugin that might resize the video (double the size for example) but haven't found anything.

How can I increase the view size of these videos without going all the way to full screen?

Comment: Have you tried [PopVideo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/popvideo/)? "PopVideo is a completely free add-on that pops out your web videos into resizable windows. Use our lightweight and powerful add-on to create a more immersive and enjoyable video viewing experience."

Comment: @DavidPostill - I tried it but it doesn't work on the webm/gifv videos.  Just things like youtube.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're watching them in Firefox, you can zoom in. 
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>+</kbd>**
(which, strictly speaking, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>
on most keyboards) to zoom in (i.e., enlarge),
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>-</kbd>** to zoom out (i.e., shrink),
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to reset. 
Or you can use the "View" → "Zoom" menu to achieve the same results. 
You can do the same thing in Internet Explorer
(it lets you zoom to a user-specified magnification factor, unlike Firefox,
which, AFAIK, only lets you navigate the hard-coded magnification levels).

I don't know specifically about WEBMs,
but I do this with animated GIFs with no problem.

Obviously, there's a limit (300%? 400%?) to how far you can magnify an image
before pixelation sets in. 
If the original image is *too* small, you'll hit that limit
before you enlarge the image enough to make it properly visible.

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was looking for as this zooms the entire page instead of just the video, but it's better than nothing, thanks!